# Implementing history functions in a simple shell (in C)

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am completely new to programming in C, taking a C/UNIX course currently. I am having a bit of an issue starting this assignment...it is the first C program we've been assigned, but the professor has been extremely scant in explaining what is needed to accomplish it or where to begin, and asking him hasn't accomplished much. Being that I've done very little C, I'm not sure where to begin with this.

The program is a simple shell that I am supposed to implement some history features into. The source code for the shell has been given. Supposed to add these abilities:

history - type history at command line, most recent shell commands displayed with number in front (starting at 1). Commands are to be stored in a text file. I am assuming the history command will just print this text file each time.

!number - type this at command line, the command in the file with that number will be re-executed

!string - type this at command line, re-execute the last command that begins with that string

!! - type at command line, re-execute the previous command

Source code (this is one of three files for the shell, but I believe the one that is supposed to be edited):

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
char input[MAXINPUTLINE];

signal_c_init();

printf("Welcome to the sample shell!  You may enter commands here, one\n");
printf("per line.  When you're finished, press Ctrl+D on a line by\n");
printf("itself.  I understand basic commands and arguments separated by\n");
printf("spaces, redirection with < and >, up to two commands joined\n");
printf("by a pipe, tilde expansion, and background commands with &.\n\n");


while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) {
stripcrlf(input);
parse(input);
printf("\n$ ");
}
return 0;
}
```

Let me just state for the record that I'm not asking anyone to do my homework here. I just literally do not know where to begin with this and no indications have been given. Without much experience in this language prior to the class, I don't have comparable knowledge of how this type of thing is achieved. Any kind of resource or functions that I could begin with would be helpful.

Comment: FYI, there's a specific shell called the "C shell". It looks like you're implementing things in your own shell, in C. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: I will revise that, thanks.

Comment: There are a ton of questions here at SO about implementing a simple shell in C. Try looking at them (see right side of page).

Comment: creating your own shell for school is a common topic here on S.O. Try searching for `[c] code school history` (just guessing, but you get the idea). While all available shell source code for the big 3/4? shells is available and have history code, they are usually shrouded in layers of protective functionality that would make it difficult for a beginner programmer to understand the basic concepts. Divide and conquer says to get so you can just capture your history to a file THEN display the whole history AND THEN think about  searching that history. Good luck.

Comment: I find it a bit odd that the first thing in C we are doing is implementing a shell...seems like some basics first would make it less confusing, especially since this course required no prior knowledge of C. I will check that out! Thanks.

Comment: Well, some hints about your current code: check return values of `fgets`, you should not use it in `while` loop condition quite like that. Use proper indentation. The `parse` function, assuming it comes from `parser.h` or something, study what it does. If it is a function you're supposed to add, then start working in small steps, like 1. print input. 2. separate and print first word only. 3. separate and print all words. 4. test if first word is a known command like `history`... and so on.

Comment: you need to select a data structure (an array of strings or maybe a list of strings) to store the commands issued to the shell and then apply operations to this data structure (find(), last(), add() ... ) and for extra credit store this data structure to a file.

Answer (score 1):

To handle history (and command line editing, and...) check out the readline or editline libraries.